# Inequality $|ab|+1\leq |ab-b| + |b-1|$ for real numbers $a,b$

Tags: inequality, real-numbers

How do I prove $$|ab|+1\leq |ab-b| + |b-1|$$ for $a,b\in \Bbb R$ ?

I tried using the triangle inequality $|ab|+1\leq |ab-b|+|b|+1$ but it doesn't give the result. I also tried using the reverse triangle inequality but to no success.

Comment: This inequality is false. Take $a = b = 1$.

Comment: No wonder I couldn't prove it...thanks